# what is the problem in my code?why it in not being acceptedd for uri problem no:1040

Tags: c, windows, uri, dynamic-programming, codeblocks

The reason for not accepting my code is showing "wrong code(100%)"I have looked at some solutions over the internet.They seem to be quite alike my code. [URI problem no:1040](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1040)

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

int main(){

```
double N1,N2,N3,N4,average,average_2,xm_score;
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&N1,&N2,&N3,&N4);
average=((N1*2)+(N2*3)+(N3*4)+(N4*1))/(10);
printf("Media: %.1lf\n",average);
if(average>=7.0){
    printf("Aluno aprovado.\n");
}

else if(average<7.0&&average>=5.0){
    printf("Aluno em exame.\n");

    scanf("%lf",&xm_score);
    printf("Nota do exame: %.1lf\n",xm_score);
    average_2=(average+xm_score)/2;
    if(average_2>=5.0){
        printf("Aluno reprovado.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Aluno reprovado.\n");
    }
    printf("Media final: %.1lf\n",average_2);
}
else{
printf("Aluno reprovado.\n");
}
```

return 0;
}

Comment: For *what reason* is the code not accepted? Compilation error, runtime error, wrong answer, time limit, source code size...

Comment: Typo: you `printf("Aluno reprovado.\n");` regardless of the range. Please fully test the code before submitting to the judge.

Comment: Hint: Learn to use the `else` clause.

Comment: @WeatherVane "wrong code(100%)"

Comment: @fpiette the result is same,not accepted

Comment: https://www.codeshikhi.com/2020/12/uri-1040-average-3-solution-in-c-cpp-cpluscplus-python.html
here is a solution over the problem.